# $_POST['multipart/form-data'] file name does not appear

Tags: php

```
<?php


echo $_POST['userfile'];



?>

    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">  

<INPUT NAME='userfile' TYPE='file' size="90" id="upl" style="color:#000000;"><br>

<input type="submit" value="submit">

</form>
```

Any ideas why does not `$_POST['userfile'];` echo?

Comment: [Get busy](http://il.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)

Comment: Could you put this as an answer, so I can accept :)

Answer (score 5):

Read the manual on **[Handling File Uploads](http://il.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)**, and specifically the `$_FILES` super global.

The correct way to display the file name is using the following:

```
echo $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
```

Answer (score 3):

Try echoing this, just to begin with! :)

```
$_FILES['userfile']['name']
```